# Vue Syntax for calculating value instead of rendering text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Having a senior moment.. I can't remember how to render the value of the equation instead of just rendering the text in this scenario.

```
<v-icon>{{ item.photo ? check_circle : cancel }}</v-icon>
```

So if `item.photo` is true I want to render a `check_cricle` icon or if false the `cancel` icon.

There is some combination of quotes and I can't remember what it is!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I ended up getting it. I just created a method like this:

```
returnPhotoIcon(value) {
 return value ? 'check_circle' : 'cancel'
}
```

Then in my `icon` field I did this:

```
<v-icon>{{ returnPhotoIcon(item.photo) }}</v-icon>
```

Hope this helps someone!